# stdClass objects and array key value

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

I have the following objects with arrays and trying to get the value of email. How can this be done?

```
stdClass Object (
    [status] => stdClass Object ( 
        [info] => Unsubscribe List [code] => 200 
    ) 
    [data] => Array ( 
        [o1958147@rtrtr.com] => stdClass Object ( 
            [date] => 2013-01-28 08:09:19 
            [origin] => 
        ) 
        [phil.houston@granherne.com] => stdClass Object ( 
            [date] => 2013-01-28 08:35:59 
            [origin] => 
        ) 
    )    
)
```

Currently i can access the date values with the following foreach.

```
foreach ($fnret->data as $msg)
{
    echo $msg->date;      // shows 2013-01-28 08:35:59
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($array as $key => $value)` is the answer. The `$key` holds value of what is in `[]` brackets. `[key] => value`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one should work :

```
foreach ($fnret->data as $email => $msg) {
    // echo $msg->date;      // shows 2013-01-28 08:35:59
    echo $email;
}
```

Comment: To clarify it a bit so it does not look like magic. It's simple `foreach ($array as $key => $value)` statement. Meaning, this would be the input `$array = Array ("key" => "value", 0 => 42, "p1" => "another");`